# How get actual value of variable from method of another class?

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a variable `idTransportType` in `FirstTableViewController`.

In this class I change `idTransportType` some times and last time I call it in `cellForRowAt indexPath`.

So, I have another class `RouteAction` and I need call `idTransportType` in it with *actual* (not 0) value that is in `cellForRowAt indexPath` of my first class - `FirstTableViewController`. When I call it in method of another class I see `idTransportType = 0`, but actual value isn't 0.

Where is my mistake and how get actual value?

upd. code of calling in another class:

```
class RouteAction {

    class func workingWithAnoterClass()  {

        let callVC = FirstTableViewController()
        var getidTransportTypeFromAnotherClass = callVC.idTransportType
        print(getidTransportTypeFromAnotherClass)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code, where you call this property in the other class?

Comment: Do you have the current `FirstTableViewController ` instance that are in your  `RouteAction ` class? It seems like you create new `FirstTableViewController` so it will give u default value of that variable

Comment: Maybe you are accessing it after calling constructor of `FirstTableViewController`, and that call makes the value to default `0`

Comment: @RobertKhayreev, please see, I added code of calling variable

Comment: @Tj3n how to get current instance of `FirstTableViewController` and not create new? I added my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you initialize a new instance of that class, instead of using the current one. You should use it like this:

```
class RouteAction {
    class func workingWithAnoterClass(firstTableVC: FirstTableViewController)  {

        var getidTransportTypeFromAnotherClass = firstTableVC.idTransportType
        print(getidTransportTypeFromAnotherClass)
    }
}
```

And somewhere `FirstTableViewController` you should call the following:

```
RouteAction.workingWithAnotherClass(firstTableVC: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to get last view controller, instead to create a new one, like this:

```
 class RouteAction {

    func getCurrentViewController() -> UIViewController {
        var currentViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!!.rootViewController!
        while (currentViewController.presentedViewController != nil) {
            currentViewController = currentViewController.presentedViewController!
        }
        return currentViewController ViewController
    }

    class func workingWithAnoterClass()  {

        let callVC = getCurrentViewController()
        var getidTransportTypeFromAnotherClass = callVC.idTransportType
        print(getidTransportTypeFromAnotherClass)
    }

}
```